# Check if record does NOT exist in Rails (from array of ids)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I can do this to check if a record(s) exists (say id "1" exists, but "2" and "3" don't):

```
Model.exists?(:id => [1, 2, 3]) #=> true
```

How do I do the opposite, so:

```
Model.not_exists?(:id => [1, 2, 3]) #=> true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Please don't use this method. Even if it works it's not optimal since it loads all records instead of only testing their existence. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30531384/508684) is a better way of doing it.

---

If you only need search records through ID you can try this

```
class Model
  def self.not_exists?(ids)
    self.find(ids)
    false
  rescue
    true
  end
end
```

If any of the IDs does not exist the `find` method will raise a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception that we simply catch and return true.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, rescue as its used is dangerous and `find` will load the records where you only care at the existence of a raw. Answer belong should be the one accepted

Answer (score 35):

just add a ! operator

```
!Model.exists?(:id => [1, 2, 3]) #=> true
```

Comment: I'm asking how to say if `2` and `3` don't exist, how to make it return false.  `!Model.exists?(:id => [1, 2, 3])` returns `false` if `1` exists, whereas I want `Model.not_exists?(:id => [1, 2, 3])` to return true if any don't exist.

Comment: `Model.find(ids_ary).count` then `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Answer (score 4):

Use `empty?`, this is what you want.  It uses `count(*)` vs `select 1 as one`.

```
> Rocketeer.where(:id => [1, 2, 3]).empty?
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "rocketeers" WHERE "rocketeers"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
=> false

> Rocketeer.where(:id => [1, 2, 3]).any?
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "rocketeers" WHERE "rocketeers"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
=> true

> Rocketeer.where(:id => [1, 2, 3]).exists?
  Rocketeer Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "rocketeers" WHERE "rocketeers"."id" IN (1, 2, 3) LIMIT 1
=> true
```

Comment: Isn't `SELECT 1 AS one ... LIMIT 1` more efficient than `SELECT COUNT(*)`?

Comment: `limit 1` is equal or faster than `count(*)`. Although generally it'll be only perceptible with a combination of table size and index keys. Also, favor use of `empty?` to save DB RTT, if you'll use matching records.

Answer (score 2):

A more Ruby-esque way of doing it would be to use `unless` with `exists?`. This way, you don't have to use `!`. I imagine your use case is something like this:

```
def my_method
    return unless Model.exists?(:id => [1, 2, 3])

    # do something
end
```

You can replace `1, 2, 3` with a variable (call it `id` or something) and even remove the array altogether if you'd like: `.exists?(id: id)`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Model
  def self.does_not_exist?(ids)
    Model.where(id: ids).count < ids.size
  end
end
```

Explanation: If (and only if) all the instances you're looking for exist, `Model.where(id: ids).count` is equal to `ids.size`.

However if there are one or more instances missing, the count will be lower, meaning that there's a record that does not exist.

Comment: Maybe with an explanation it's more helpful

Comment: It answers the question but is slower performance for a large number of rows. It does a `COUNT` in SQL which counts every row in a table. `where(id: [1, 2, 3]).exists?` on the other hand does a `SELECT... WHERE... LIMIT 1` which will return first row it finds. See @mwoods79 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30531384/34315).

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to use the where method with an array of id's.

```ruby
# If the count of the query is equal to the count of all of the id's then the statement will return false.
# Else it will return true if not all ids exists in the database.
Model.where(id: [1, 2, 3]).count < [1,2,3].count
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure all ids exist, not just one the following works without have to rescue

```
ids = [1,2,3]
Model.where(id: ids).count != ids.length
```

The exists? method will return true if any of the ids match. The above will ensure all ids exist.